# Vue component not update v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

I create a component for input radio like this

```
<template>
    <input
       :id="id"
        ref="radio"
        type="radio"
        :name="name"
        @change="$emit('input', value)"
    />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
    name: 'InputRadio',
    components: { HeadingS },
    props: {
        id: {
            type: String,
            default: 'radio',
        },
        value: {
            type: String,
            default: undefined,
        },
        name: {
            type: String,
            default: undefined,
        },
    },
}
```

Then i use it

```
<InputRadio
   :id="'false'"
   v-model="form.date"
   :name="'date'"
   :value="false"
/>
 <InputRadio
   :id="'true'"
   v-model="form.date"
   :name="'date'"
   :value="true"
/>
```

The problem: V-model (form.date) doesn't update value to true/false. I think that is emit is wrong but i don´t know why. So, anybody see the error?

Comment: if u set up a playground will be easier to help u https://sfc.vuejs.org

Comment: @ericmp the syntax is different for vue 3, and the OP is using vue 2

Comment: i thought in the link i shared u could switch between versions. i guess there is vue2 playgrounds online

Comment: @ericmp, yes, something like https://playcode.io/

Answer (score 0):

```
<InputRadio
   :id="'false'"
   v-model="form.date"
   :name="'date'"
   :option="false"
/>
 <InputRadio
   :id="'true'"
   v-model="form.date"
   :name="'date'"
   :option="true"
/>
```

I changed  'value' string for 'option' and works properly